# Usage of picture tag for svg types

Tags: html, image, css, svg

When I want to load pictures (in png or jpg format) for different screen types I
use picture tag and describe sources:

```html
<picture>
  <source
    media="(min-width: 960px)"
    srcset="img/photo-drumset-desktop@1x.jpg 1x, img/photo-drumset-desktop@2x.jpg 2x"
    alt="Фотография пользователя"
  />
  <source
    media="(min-width: 660px)"
    srcset="img/photo-drumset-tablet@1x.jpg 1x, img/photo-drumset-tablet@2x.jpg 2x"
    alt="Фотография пользователя"
  />
  <img
    src="img/photo-drumset-mobile.jpg"
    srcset="img/photo-drumset-mobile.jpg 1x, img/photo-drumset-mobile@2x.jpg 2x"
    alt="Фотография пользователя из социальной сети"
  />
</picture>
```

What is better way to use it for svg tag (and then use fill and other css
properties for it)? (without js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends, if you want/will use:

- inline `SVG`

or

- `SVG` as image (*ex:* `<img src="someimage.svg" alt="svg" />`)

---

If you want/will use  `SVG` as `img` then you can do as you have it at the moment using `picture`.

Otherwise you will have to use CSS media queries, something like this:

```css
/*demo purposes */
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden
}

svg {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
/* end demo purposes */

.mobile {
  background: red
}

.desktop {
  display: none
}

@media (min-width:1024px) {
  .desktop {
    background: green;
    display: block
  }
  .mobile {
    display: none
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class="desktop">
 <!-- svg code -->
</svg>
<svg class="mobile">
 <!-- svg code -->
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<foreignObject>` tag in SVG ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject)):

```html
<svg>
 <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
   <picture>
      <source media="(min-width: 960px)"
              srcset="img/photo-drumset-desktop@1x.jpg 1x, img/photo-drumset-desktop@2x.jpg 2x"
              alt="Фотография пользователя">
      <source media="(min-width: 660px)"
              srcset="img/photo-drumset-tablet@1x.jpg 1x, img/photo-drumset-tablet@2x.jpg 2x"
              alt="Фотография пользователя">
      <img src="img/photo-drumset-mobile.jpg"
            srcset="img/photo-drumset-mobile.jpg 1x, img/photo-drumset-mobile@2x.jpg 2x"
            alt="Фотография пользователя из социальной сети">
    </picture>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```